# Elasticsearch function_score with nested geolocation

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, geolocation, nested

I'm trying to implement *function_score* with geo location, similar to what's described in [Elastic Search Geo Distance Sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/decay-functions.html). However my documents geo-location field is in a array which has a nested mapping.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "bo_contentmodel": {
      "properties": {
        "contentId": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "contentName": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "no"
        },
        "geoInfo": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "geoPhone": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "no"
            },
            "geoTitle": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "no"
            },
            "point": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When performing the following query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 6,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [{
        "filter": {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "geo_distance": {
                "distance": "800.0m",
                "geoInfo.point": {
                  "lat": 4.654159,
                  "lon": -74.11392
                }
              }
            },
            "path": "geoInfo"
          }
        },
        "gauss": {
          "geoInfo.point": {
            "origin": {
              "lat": 4.654159,
              "lon": -74.11392
            },
            "scale": "0.5km",
            "offset": "0.01km"
          }
        },
        "weight": 200
      }],
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
```

The following result is obtained:

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1377,
    "max_score": 200,
    "hits": [{
      "_index": "contents",
      "_type": "bo_contentmodel",
      "_id": "665",
      "_score": 200,
      "_source": {
        "contentId": 665,
        "contentName": "BOG - CAL - MED - Gurú - Rosas Don Eloy",
        "geoInfo": [{
          "point": {
            "lat": 4.652946,
            "lon": -74.111271
          },
          "geoPhone": "Carrera 68D #23B - 25 local 7",
          "geoTitle": "Rosas Don Eloy"
        }, {
          "point": {
            "lat": 4.61455,
            "lon": -74.068151
          },
          "geoPhone": " Calle 27B #6 - 73 Esquina",
          "geoTitle": "Rosas Don Eloy"
        }, {
          "point": {
            "lat": 6.208072,
            "lon": -75.567081
          },
          "geoPhone": "Carrera 37 #8A - 51 El Poblado",
          "geoTitle": "Rosas Don Eloy"
        }]
      }
    }, {
      "_index": "contents",
      "_type": "bo_contentmodel",
      "_id": "968",
      "_score": 200,
      "_source": {
        "contentId": 968,
        "contentName": "Bogotá - Gurú - Maloka",
        "geoInfo": [{
          "point": {
            "lat": 4.655359,
            "lon": -74.109347
          },
          "geoPhone": "Cra. 68 D # 24 A - 51",
          "geoTitle": "Maloka en Bogotá"
        }]
      }
    }, {
      "_index": "contents",
      "_type": "bo_contentmodel",
      "_id": "1328",
      "_score": 200,
      "_source": {
        "contentId": 1328,
        "contentName": "PuntoFarma Final",
        "geoInfo": [{
          "point": {
            "lat": 4.710077,
            "lon": -74.05901
          },
          "geoPhone": "Calle 127b # 50A-65",
          "geoTitle": "La Cosecha"
        }, {
          "point": {
            "lat": 4.71885,
            "lon": -74.035316
          },
          "geoPhone": "Calle 140 # 11 - 01  Cedritos",
          "geoTitle": "Montearroyo 2"
        }, {
          "point": {
            "lat": 4.731724,
            "lon": -74.045728
          },
          "geoPhone": "Calle 150 # 19 A - 06",
          "geoTitle": "Las Margaritas"
        }, {
          "point": {
            "lat": 4.618438,
            "lon": -74.071008
          },
          "geoPhone": "Calle 31 # 13A - 51 Torre 2 Local 15",
          "geoTitle": "Panorama"
        }, {
          "point": {
            "lat": 4.721164,
            "lon": -74.039739
          },
          "geoPhone": "Carrera 13 No. 140 - 21",
          "geoTitle": "Cedritos"
        }, {
          "point": {
            "lat": 4.656416,
            "lon": -74.107209
          },
          "geoPhone": "Carrera 68 D # 25 B - 86 Local 1-17",
          "geoTitle": "Torre Central"
        }]
      }
    }, {
      "_index": "contents",
      "_type": "bo_contentmodel",
      "_id": "14",
      "_score": 1,
      "_source": {
        "contentId": 14,
        "contentName": "Alumbrado en Medellín 2013",
        "geoInfo": []
      }
    }, {
      "_index": "contents",
      "_type": "bo_contentmodel",
      "_id": "19",
      "_score": 1,
      "_source": {
        "contentId": 19,
        "contentName": "Bogotá Despierta Final",
        "geoInfo": []
      }
    }, {
      "_index": "contents",
      "_type": "bo_contentmodel",
      "_id": "22",
      "_score": 1,
      "_source": {
        "contentId": 22,
        "contentName": "Pastelería Jacques",
        "geoInfo": []
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

As you can see, the first three documents have the same score **(Here the error)** It is expected that the score changes, since the geo-points are different.

Is it posible?, how can i implement it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer to this/

Comment: No i still don't find it. But i didn't test it in new releases.